# NSString unichar from int

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an `int` value which I obtained from the character 爸, which is 29240. I can convert this number to hex, but I have no clue how to write the chinese character out in an `NSString` with only the `int 29240`.

Basically, what I did was:

```
NSString * s = @"爸";
int a = [s characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%d", a);
```

What it gave as output was 29240.

However, I don't know how to create an `NSString` that just contains 爸 from only the `int 29240`.

I converted 29240 into binary which gave me 7238, but I can't seem to create a method which allows me to input any integer and `NSLog` the corresponding character.
I can hard code it in, so that I have

```
char cString[] = "\u7238";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result string: %@", string);
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with any int.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a string from one (or more) Unicode characters use `initWithCharacters`:

```
unichar c = 29240;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c length:1];
```

`NSString` uses UTF-16 characters internally, so 
this works for all characters in the "Basic Multilingual Plane", i.e. all characters up to `U+FFFF`. The following code works for arbitrary characters:

```
uint32_t ch = 0x1F60E;
ch = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(ch); // To make it byte-order safe
NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&ch length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", s1);
// Output:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code snippet to get you started in the right direction:

```
NSString *s = @"0123456789";
for (int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Value: %d", [s characterAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Just pass in the character as an integer:

```
unichar decimal = 12298;
NSString *charStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", decimal];
```